# Updating a column of cells with a maximum value from Google Finance

Tags: google-sheets

```
function getHigh() {
  //to update the highest value of a stock price at market close, used to calculate a trailing stop price
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //column E is stock price at close, from google finance
  var eRange = sh.getRange("E2:E");
  var eValues = sh.getSheetValues(2, 5, 999, 1);
  //column H to be the highest value of a stock at market close since purchase  
  var hRange = sh.getRange("H2:H");
  var hValues = sh.getSheetValues(2, 8, 999, 1 );
  //if column E values are greater than column H replace them, if not leave them unchanged

  if(eValues > hValues);  { 
    hRange.setValues(eValues)
  }
}
```

When I run the script, it seems to ignore the `if(eValues > hValues)`  and replace hValues with eValues.

Answer (score 3):

The `eValues` and `hValues` are [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (more specifically, double arrays). To compare their values one by one, you should access individual values [in a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) using index notation such as `eValues[i][0]` and `hValues[i][0]`, and make changes there.

Also, for optimal performance `setValue` should not be used in a loop; rather, collect the values you want to set and set all at once.

```
for (var i = 0; i < eValues.length; i++) {
  if (eValues[i][0] > hValues[i][0]); { 
    hValues[i][0] = eValues[i][0];
  }
}
sh.getRange("H2:H").setValues(hValues);
```

This can be shortened:

```
for (var i = 0; i < eValues.length; i++) {
  eValues[i][0] = Math.max(hValues[i][0], eValues[i][0]);
}
sh.getRange("H2:H").setValues(hValues);
```